# how to get exact slide position in carousel in kivy?

Tags: android, python, user-interface, kivy

In kivy I want to use carousel, but I find I need not only the current slide, but also the exact position of slide when carousel is sliding left and right (when sliding is going). Could I do this with carousel? Or I should use other widget or must implement one by myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to make this a comment but that requires just more rep than I currently have.

Do you mean which one of the available slides is frontmost? Carousel has an index property for that: [Kivy Carousel Docs —](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#kivy.uix.carousel.Carousel.index) http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#kivy.uix.carousel.Carousel.index

If you mean how much the current frontmost slide is offset while animating I don't think there's a way to do that easily but it could probably be faked using min_move, scroll_distance, and the touch event leading to the Carousel change.

Comment: I mean the offset while animating. Thanks for reply and sorry for my English :-)

Comment: If the answer was helpful don't forget to accept it.